# Go to specific step in form wizard

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

Is it possible to add a button on a FormWizard form which can direct the user to a specific step in the wizard?

I can obviously get them to go back or start again but I'd like to be able to offer the chance to go to a specific step and change their entries.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible. Simplest way is to use [NamedUrlWizardView](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#usage-of-namedurlwizardview)

If you use simple [WizardView](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#creating-a-wizardview-subclass), you have to send `wizard_goto_step` parameter with a value equal to step name.

Let's say you have `WizardView` with steps like next

```
class OrderWizardView(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = (
        ('select_customer', forms.WizardCustomerForm),
        ('products', forms.WizardProductFormset),
        ('order', forms.WizardOrderForm),
        ('customer', forms.WizardCustomerDetailsForm),
        ('review', forms.WizardReviewForm),
    )
```

For Previous/First step you can use `{{ wizard.steps.prev }}` and `{{ wizard.steps.first }}` template variables.

```
<button name="wizard_goto_step" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">First Step</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">Prev Step</button>
```

If you need a specific step - use its name!

```
<button name="wizard_goto_step" value="select_customer">Select customer</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" value="products">Add products</button>
...
<button name="wizard_goto_step" value="review">Review</button>
```

Comment: How can I use it with <a> tag?

Comment: check docs for `NamedUrlWizardView.get_step_url` https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.NamedUrlWizardView.get_step_url